# Div is not showing when call a javascript function to show it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in `JavaScript` & `jQuery` so, kindly don't mind my very basic question:

I have made the following div which I want to show when certain `JavaScript` function being called:

```
<div id='faix' class="bg4 w460 h430 tac poa dpn">
    <h4 class="fwb fs22 cf3 mb5 ff3 mt150 ">Thank you John for contacting us!</h4><h4 class="fwb fs22 cf3 mb5 ff3"> We will get in touch with you shortly.</h4>
</div>
```

but when that function being called and I passed this to that function then the respective div with id of "faix" is not showing up

```
$('#faix').fadeIn(500);
```

What am I doing wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok; I think you're calling it, when the html isn't build yet. Wrap your code in a [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#faix').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have put the

```
$('#faix').fadeIn(500);
```

into

```
$(function() {
    $('#faix').fadeIn(500);
});
```

because it should, wenn jQuery is ready.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your code between :

```
$(function(){

});
```

and see if your div is hidden using css by the following code for cross browser compatibility:

```
display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure none of those classes `bg4 w460 h430 tac poa dpn` says something like `display:none !important` or `visibility:hidden !important` or `margin-top: -99999px` that kind of stuff.

After you make the call, use Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I) to find the sick div and look at its CSS properties to determine whether it should be visible or something else prevents you from seeing it. Also look at Console to watch for errors, maybe it's in a train of functions and if one fail, subsequent functions fail too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the basic things like have you imported jquery api, putting it within document.ready function etc.

Also I remember encountering such a problem once due to a div id clashing with possibly a div name in jquery api, so try changing the div name.